# Perl - CPANM installing into C:\Perl\lib\perl5 folder instead of C:\Perl\lib

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpanm

I am using CPANM to install modules on a WIN32 machine, using CPANM because the machine has no access to the internet.

My perl install is in C:\Perl and my lib folder is C:\Perl\lib

CPANM modules and dependencies were downloaded locally on a different machine using the following  (example on how I downloaded MIME::Lite) :-

```
cpanm -q --scandeps MIME::Lite --save-dists c:\dist
```

Using following to install MIME::Lite on the other machine

```
cpanm --mirror file:///C:/dist/ -l c:/perl MIME::Lite
```

The issue is that cpanm is installing my modules in C:\Perl\lib\perl5 but I instead want the modules installed in C:\Perl\lib

I have no idea how to override this default behavior.

Environment is Windows, excerpt from Perl -V

```
  ActivePerl Build 2003 [299574]
  Built under MSWin32
  Compiled at Dec 25 2015 11:33:14
  %ENV:
    PERL5LIBX="%PERL5LIB%"
    PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=y"
  @INC:
    C:/Perl/site/lib
    C:/Perl/lib
    .
```

Comment: Start by unsetting env var `PERL_MM_OPT`. It's value is garbage anyway. (`PERL5LIBX` also appears to contains garbage, but I'm not aware of anything that uses that variable.) Then, please provide the output of `perl -V:inst.*lib`

Comment: Thank You and here is the output: perl -V:inst.*lib
installarchlib='C:\Perl\lib';
installprivlib='C:\Perl\lib';
installsitelib='C:\Perl\site\lib';
installvendorlib='';

Comment: @ikegami - Thank you for your input, I got rid of the env var you suggested and then used cpanm --mirror file:///c:/dist/  MIME::Lite

Answer (score 0):

`cpanm`'s `-l` option and `PERL_MM_OPT`'s `INSTALL_BASE` option override the installation locations. Without them, the library's installer will get the correct installation path from `perl`. In other words, changing

```
set PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=y"
set PERL_MB_OPT=
cpanm --mirror file:///C:/dist/ -l c:/perl MIME::Lite
```

to

```
set PERL_MM_OPT=
set PERL_MB_OPT=
cpanm --mirror file:///c:/dist/ MIME::Lite
```

worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, and after some posts I found [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=865684):

> CORE modules are installed under perl/lib whereas non-CORE modules
>   install under perl/site/lib.
>
> the modules that came with your original installation go into lib.
>   Newer versions go into site/lib. At least on ActiveState Perl and
>   Strawberry Perl, both on Windows.